# script with fixed Lane ID

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

how can I fixe the lane ID for vehicles or trucks in my script with VEINS. I want to have vehicles only on lane 1 and trucks travelling only on lane 2. Thanks you for your help.

I want to have 20 trucks travelling on Lane 1 and 2 vehicles travelling on lane 2

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your network with SUMO's netedit such that it allows only certain vehicle types on a lane. Just click on the lane and press the allow button which will let you select the vehicle classes which are allowed.